# param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, nested-resources

I have two models: `Boards` and `Topics`. I want to be able to add `Topics` to `Boards`. My nested resources are:

```
resources :boards do 
    resources :topics
end
```

My 'boards#show' action:

```
def show 
    @board = Board.find(params[:id])
    @new_topics = Topic.all
end
```

which lists all posts and has a `link_to`:

```
<ul>
    <%@new_topics.each do |i|%>
        <li><%=i.title%> <%=link_to "Add", board_topic_path(@board,i), :method=> :put%></li>
    <%end%>
</ul>
```

I'm also using strong_params for my `Boards` and `Topics` controller as follows:

**boards_controller:**

```
def update
    @board = Board.find(params[:board_id])
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])        

    if @board.update(board_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Added!"
        @board.topics << @topic
        redirect_to boards_path

    else
        flash[:alert] = "Problem!"
        redirect_to boards_path
    end

end

...
private

def board_params
    params.require(:board).permit(:name,:description)
end
```

**topics_controller:**

```
...
private

def topic_params
    params.require(:topic).permit(:title,:body,:user_id)
end
```

the error message I'm getting: *param is missing or the value is empty: topic*.

Comment: The whole setup is wrong. Your link with `put` method does not pass any `topic` query param. That's why you get this error. Besides that, the link should have been with `board_topic_path(@board, i)` instead. But still, this will not solve your problem.

The model design is wrong. You assume in your resources that topics belong to boards, but I see your controller loads topics with `Topic.all`, which means that the topics exist on their own, and they do not belong to boards. You need to rethink your design my friend.

Comment: Already tried swapping the two variables in link_to. Didn't help. My `controller#show` action lists all topics as `Topic.all`, and they exist on there own here, because I want to be able to see a list of all topics and be able add them to the current board, with  `@board.topics << @topic`, which is triggered by the `link_to`. What would be your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your design is wrong.

Starting from the beginning, I would say that you have a business model `Board` that references one or more `Topics` and a `Topic` that is referenced by one or more `Boards`. So, logically you have something like this:

[image: Boards&Topics]

So, these are two independent resources, that they have a many-to-many relationship.

My model with Rails would have been:

```
# routes
resources :boards
resources :topics
```

In other words, topics are not nested resource of boards. If it were, this would mean that the topics of a board would die when the board would die. Which is not your case here, as far as I understand.

Now, since the relationship is many-to-many, then you will need a 3rd table to hold your associations (table `boards` and table `topics` are not enough). Read this on [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

Briefly:

```
class Board
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end

class Topic
  has_and_belongs_to_many :boards
end
```

Now, if you want to add topics to boards on your UI, then you need to have a form to edit the board. This form, besides the others, needs to have a multiple select box with the topics that would be added to the board. Then on your `boards_controller#update` method the `param[:board]` would have an attribute `topic_ids[]` which will automatically be used to associate the particular/selected topics to the board that you are editing. Rails does that automatically.

*Note* I am not inclined to be using `has_and_belongs_to_many` Rails association. It has a lot of limitations. You can always design your own table that will hold the many-to-many association and other extra attributes that your business model will require. For example, for each topic that is attached to a board, you might want to hold the subject, or the author. I do not know. In that case a more custom model might be needed:

```
class Board
  has_many :board_topics
  has_many :topics, through: :board_topics
end

class Topic
  has_many :board_topics
  has_many :boards, through: :board_topics
end

class BoardTopic
  belongs_to :topic, inverse_of: :board_topics
  belongs_to :board, inverse_of: :board_topics
  .... add other attributes that give real business value to this association ....
 end
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the two models already had `many-to-many` relationships via `has_and_belongs_to`. I think the entire issues is caused by the way my app handles `strong_params` for models with `many-to-many relations`, because `reply` and 'topic` models, with ':reply belongs_to :topic' relation,  handle the same scenario without returning any errors. I do not want to use a form to be able to add topics to boards, I'm specifically using a `link_to` as it would make more sense to give end-user the ability to add topics to boards directly on the `board#show`.

Answer (score 0):

In a RESTful situation as yours, with that link you should be hitting the `update` action of `TopicsController` with two `params`: `board_id` and `id`.

Try this instead:

```
# boards_controller.rb
def update
   @board = Board.find(params[:id])
   @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])        

if @board.update(board_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Added!"
    @board.topics << @topic
    redirect_to boards_path

else
    flash[:alert] = "Problem!"
    redirect_to boards_path
end

end

# In the view 
<%=link_to "Add", board_path(@board, topic_id: i.id), :method=> :put%>
```

Still, this is still off from any convention, as you are not updating a whole topic. You probably want to use an extra action to add a topic to a board, using the PATCH verb.